# Fetching local text file using XmlHttpRequest in Reactjs works properly while it does not work in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have some local text files which are fetched using `xmlHttpRequest` properly in **reactjs** `componentDidMount` life-cycle method. I am going to have ssr for my app and I decided to use **Nextjs** for this purpose. However, such local files are not fetched with `xmlHttpRequest` in Nextjs and error is shown while fetching.
I have installed **webpack** `raw-loader` and `file-loader` and added relevant config to `next.config.js` to solve this issue with no result.
How can I tackle this issue in **Nextjs** since it's an ssr framework and some codes in client-side ones might not be read in server-side?

Comment: `componentDidMount` get executed just in the client side so there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: I think the problem might be related to webpack config for loading raw files that should be added to nextjs config

Comment: Also, I dont know if these files are rendered in client side, they can be rendered in server- side as well or not since. they are important for SEO